# Has the C++1y standard considered to support coroutine/goroutine?

Tags: c++, standards, coroutine, c++14, goroutine

I think coroutine/goroutine is very useful in case of a lot of concurrent small tasks must be performed quickly. Current `std::thread` cannot meet the requirements, because of its heavy cost.

I also think coroutine/goroutine cannot be supported simply through a C++ library, it should be implemented directly by the language's core features. Because coroutine/goroutine has a special semantics, which doesn't have a corresponding concept in current C++ standard.

Provided that we add a new keyword `cppgo`, then we may write code as follows:

```
void f(int n)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        cppgo f(i);
    }
}
```

**How cool it would be!**

Has the C++1y standard considered to support coroutine/goroutine?

Comment: Well, yes, maybe that's cool, but what are the rules for that? You obviously don't want to have destruction / wait at the end of scope, because then nothing is executed in parallel. What you want is either a sort of `parallel_for` or `std::async` with a low-level mechanism to decide if things are actually done elsewhere.

Comment: We can impose new rules on coroutines if necessary. Most importantly, coroutines are very useful in cloud computing. This is a strongly desired feature.

Comment: yes, new rules are possible, but I'm talking about a fairly strong one: scopes. Another thing: What happens if `f` returns something else than `void`? What happens to the return value?. You really want well-defined behaviour there, especially regarding scope. Just use async. Its default launch policy is "here or somewhere else", so basically just what you need.

Comment: `std::thread` can do any works a coroutine can do; the only difference is performance. We can think couroutines as `std::light_thread`. Your issues can be resolved by imposing some special rules.

Comment: I think you are underestimating the effort of adding these "special rules". Also, it's a fairly big deal to create new rules that fundamentally contradict existing rules, although it might be useful. People _expect_ things to be destroyed at scope-exit. That's part of the "contract" you have with the language. A fairly light-weight version of your code would be to create a thread-pool.

Comment: @xmllmx: this is not correct! a coroutine is able to leave a stackframe without destructing it and resume this stackframe if resumed. a thread can only create a stackframe and destroying it - suspending/resuming a stackframe ist not possible.

Comment: I fully know it is very hard to add new rules to the standard, but we can limit the rules within a very restricted domain. I cannot instantly imagine a feasible way to do that, but I believe there must be one.

Comment: coroutines are not equivalent to goroutines. instead fibers (which are a kind of lightweight thread) using coroutines internally provide similar facilities as goroutines. C++-coroutines are suggested by the N3708 proposal.

Comment: @olk, I say coroutines are comparable with `std::thread`, just because of their behaviors, rather than their mechanisms.

Comment: @olk, you are correct; but I think a goroutine is a refined coroutine.

Answer (score 8):

There are several proposals related to coroutines but they don't target C++14 but a later version. Here are a few of these proposals:

- [Resumable functions](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3858.pdf)  (language feature, introduce `resumable` functions and `await` instruction/expression(?))
- [A proposal to add coroutines to the C++ standard library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3708.pdf)  (library, based on [Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html))

There are other more or less related papers (look at concurrency related papers and future related papers and you'll see a tendency toward allowing coroutines).

Some people also discuss the possibility to have a general syntax for "unwrapping monads" (like the `await` keyword proposed in [1](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3858.pdf) ) which would work both for `std::future` and other non-concurrency related types like `optional` or `expected`. Such features would allow to seamlessly apply the same algorithms to both resumable and not resumable functions, with or without concurrency being involved. In theory at least.

Here is a list of discussions related to these coroutine and monad concepts, by people doing and criticizing these proposals:

- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-proposals/KCqwEq49GMA
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-proposals/monad/std-proposals/5YT_bMfXLIM/GjncYChUrl0J
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-proposals/monad/std-proposals/KCqwEq49GMA/a5f117Z5yZkJ
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-proposals/monad/std-proposals/sL6zoPI-qEk/G_V7d1NzWnQJ
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-proposals/resumable/std-proposals/LA8gxi73XYw/ilUxUO77Z9cJ
- https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-proposals/resumable/std-proposals/sL6zoPI-qEk/G_V7d1NzWnQJ